# Codeigniter 4 enviroment make JSON.parse fail

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, codeigniter-4

I'm new in codeigniter 4
I just started a new project in Codeigniter 4, and i got an error using JSON.parse,
*Unexpected token < in JSON at position 30*

I get two different results from using different enviroments:

**Default**// did not make any change to codeigniter config

-The code run totaly fine, though for a second i manage to see a bug in console

-The bad thing, in this enviroment most of debugging tools are deactivated something that i would like to have while working.

**SetEnv CI_ENVIRONMENT production** //  which makes the debugging tools from CI4 appear, this line is in .htacess

-The code stops at JSON.parse and get the error described before in console

So here it is how my code is estructured:

```
//controller
echo json_encode(array('status' => 0,'message'=>'Access denied'));


//response rgets data from callback from a controller
console.log(response);//{status:0,message:'Access denied'}
data=JSON.parse(response); //error


//Other fixes i already tried
data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); //Works fine, but returns a string, need an object

data=JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))); //error

data=JSON.parse("{status:0,message:'Access denied'} "); //Even trying to use directly a JSON format throws error

data=JSON.parse({status:0,message:'Access denied'}) //error, without the comas

data=JSON.parse([{status:0,message:'Access denied'}]) //error
```

The debbuging tools seem to stop the loading when they find a bug, but i have not managed to find what i am doing wrong. Hope you can help me with this and thanks in advance.

EDIT
I´m using webix libraries for request, but they return string format.
I tried manually what you suggested,but the result was the same. It works if use CI4 in production env, but fails at development mode.

```
//Solutions tried
response = JSON.parse({"status":0,"message":"Access denied"});//error
response = JSON.parse("{'status':0,'message':'Access denied'}");//error
```

Comment: First, your JSON format is wrong in the last three statements. JSON keys should be wrapped by double quotes such as "message". Second, if you are using library like axios, they convert your response in json object already. You do not need to run JSON.parse since it is already converted.

Answer (score 0):

echo json_encode(array('status' => 0,'message'=>'Access denied'));

//the response should be like this
{"status":0,"message":"Access denied"}

and then use like this
data=JSON.parse(response);

and kindly check your datatype during the post and it should be a json